# how do i find element <a> and click

Tags: javascript, html, jasmine, protractor

Can someone help me how do i find  and click on it using Protractor

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-8">
    <div class="nav-control pull-right">
            <li>
                <a class="btn theme-button" ng-click="loginSignUp()">Login/Signup</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

My attempts but none of them successfully so for.

```
$('.nav-control pull-right a').click();

var li = element(by.xpath('//ul/li/a'));
expect(li.getText()).toBe('Doge meme');


// by class name
element(by.className('btn theme-button')).click();

// by css
element(by.css('.btn')).click();
element(by.xpath('.//*[.="Login/Signup"]')).click();
element(by.xpath('//*[@id="top"]/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/ul/li/a')).click();
```

**Update:**

I am able to click the  tag with following code.

```
  let el = element(by.cssContainingText('a', 'Login/Signup'));      
  var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;      
  browser.driver.wait(function () {
      browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(el), 10000);
      browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(1280, 1024);
      el.click();
  });
```

However, even it clicks the anchor tag but still complains in the console

> Failed: unknown error: Element ... is not clickable at point (1164, 27).
>   Other element would receive the click: ...
>         (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)
>         (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT
>   10.0.15063 x86_64)

Comment: click() should work but maybe your not using the correct selector here: '.nav-control pull-right a'

Comment: Thats my question 'What i am doing wrong'. Can you figure out please?

Answer (score 1):

A few ways you could do it.  Also just FYI, you are missing a `.` before some of your classes.  Either way, some of those looks like they may be too vague i.e. (`.btn` probably applies to multiple elements, but thats an assumption)

Your first few attempts may work if you change this: `$('.nav-control pull-right a').click();` to this `$('.nav-control.pull-right > li > a').click();`

Or, you can try some of the below which should also work:

```
let el = $('[ng-click="loginSignUp()"]');
let el = element(by.cssContainingText('a', 'Login/Signup'));
let el = $('a.btn.btn-theme');
```

Comment: Thanks you. If i just write "let el = element(by.cssContainingText('a', 'Login/Signup'))" then I don't get any error in console and I assume protractor able to find the element BUT in next line if i write "el.click()" then I get same console error '' NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: by.cssContainingText("a", "Login/Signup")". Why?

Comment: Because there is no such class`a`, the class for the anchor tag is `btn theme-button`.

Comment: You can even use linkText. `element(by.linkText('Login/Signup')).click();`

Comment: @Barney, still same error "No element found using locator: By(link text, Login/Signup)"... I am executing this line right after Browder.get(....) line. Can this be due to the DOM has not completely loaded and hence unable to find link by almost every way? Do i need to put some wait for DOM to get completely load?

Comment: @simbada Yes that might be the issue.  Take a look at using one of the [Expected Conditions](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions).  You probably want `presenceOf` or `visibilityOf` (or both)

Comment: @Gunderson I just edited question. Please have a look. Well i am able to click the anchor tag but don't why it still complains something weird.

Comment: @simbada So that error means the element exists, but cannot be clicked at the time it executes.  A few reasons: either it's not visible (like part of a dropdown menu), or there's something else over it (like a modal) etc.  Part of that error `Other element would receive the click: ...` should tell you which element is blocking the click event.  Also, since you say you see it click the anchor tag, are you sure you don't have another click event somewhere?  Are you positive the error is coming from that line of code `el.click()`?

Comment: @simbada did my answer help you solve the problem?  seems you have moved on to a new question.  please consider marking it as correct to help others

Answer (score 0):

Can you try once with javascript executor click

```
var elm = element(by.linkText('Login/Signup'));
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", elm.getWebElement());
```